# How to get local place and business information in Google Maps while clicking on the icon?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

In the "Google Maps" app while a user clicks on the icon of a local place or business or institution(e.g ATM, Hospital icon) it shows the details of that business. I want to do the similar thing. So far what I have found is Place Picker. But for using Place Picker I have to open a different intent.

```
startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Which I don't want to do. I want to keep my user on my app map exactly like the Google Maps. I have also gone through:-

```
PlaceDetectionApi
GeoDataClient
```

PlaceDetectionApi help to find the places which are near to the user current location. And GeoDataClient helps to find a place information by using place id.
So I don't know how to get a place details while user clicks on the icon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch place data by placeId:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Comment: How can i get the placeId? @Sayan

Comment: you can get places near by your location using Google Place API and for use of Place Api see this blog : http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html
hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually you didn't get me. I want exactly what Place Picker api do. Like when user click on a business icon(ATM, Hospital) in the Google map it will show that business name and details. @Sayan

Comment: then get placeId from onActivityResult and get the details  :

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
                final String placeId = place.getId();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: my point is that I want to create my own Place Picker. I don't want to start another intent for getting this information.